# hst.actionUrl virtual configuration Hippo CMS

Tags: virtualhost, hippocms

Following the instruction [here](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/request-handling/hostname-matching.html), my website can display the contents fine.
However, handling the form submission is current a problem.

I have virtual host set up in my environment. Rendering of contents is fine but form submission ends up in a blank page.

My form is at http://mysite.local/contact

My virtual host is http://mysite.local matches to http://localhost:8080/site

My form follows the developer trail:

```
<@hst.actionURL var="actionUrl"/>
<form id="" class="form" action="${actionUrl}" method="post">
```

When I click submit, I was redirected to a blank page: `http://localhost:8080/contact?r14_r1_r1:u_u_i_d=5641b2fe-10ad-41b2-8f30-06d8a59ff451`

Using my custom component, I printed out the serverName and it's "localhost"!

How do I configure it's in the Console so that my server is "mysite.local" instead of "localhost"?

```
@Override
public void doBeforeRender(final HstRequest request,
final HstResponse response)
throws HstComponentException {
super.doBeforeRender(request, response);

l.info(request.getServerName());

}
```

Updates:
I've added the node as per Joeren's suggestion.
[image]

However it's still not working.
I event removed the "localhost" node that was orginally under hst:hosts >> dev-localhost but it broke the Site site.

I've noticed that "hst:hosts" have hst:defaulthostname set to "localhost".
I haven't dared to make the change because it would be irreversible I thought.
[image]

**Updates:**

My virtual host configuration (nginx) is as follows:

```
server {
      # listen 80;
      server_name mysite.local;

      location /site/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/site/;
        # include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
      }

      location /cms/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/cms/;
        # include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/site/;
        # include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your virtual host configuration here? Do you pass on the original host name?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, I've posted my nginx configuration there, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the host name solve the problem! Thanks to Jeroen's comment.
There is no need to update the `hst:hosts` configurations in the console though.

I've updated my nginx config to as follows:

```
server {
      # listen 80;
      server_name mysite.local;

      location /site/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/site/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      }

      location /cms/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/cms/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/site/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to the fully qualified domain name you will need to setup the virtual host in the HST configuration tree in the CMS JCR console.

If the mysite.local is a domain on your local machine you can place it in the dev-localhost host group. By creating the following nodes:

hst:hst
 + hst:hosts
   + dev-localhost
     + local
       + mysite
         + hst:root

See the [hosts configuration documentation](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/hst-configuration-model/hosts-configuration.html) for more background information. 
If you have a web server in front like apache make sure you leave the proxypreserve host on, so that the HST can detect the host. See the [Apache webserver configuration documentation](http://www.onehippo.org/library/deployment/configuring/configure-apache-httpd-web-server-for-sites.html) for more information.